# Putting Oreos in your Cholent

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, bitul-batel-null

According to the [certifying agency](https://oukosher.org/faqs/status-oreo-sandwich-cookies/) of Nabisco Oreo cookies, which are marked OU-D:

> The equipment is not necessarily cleaned before the production of these cookies, and there may be a small amount of dairy residue present. Nonetheless, the dairy component would be minimal, and from a Halachic perspective, the dairy residue is nullified (botel bishishim) and of no consequence. The bottom line of all this is that these cookies may be consumed after meat and poultry, but not simultaneously.

IMSMC, according to the Maharshal, being stringent by not relying on the halachik principle of nullification (bittul) is considered heretical/quasi-heretical (as unjustified rejection of a traditional halachik principle; as opposed to the traditional principle of *ein mevatlin issur l'chatchila* - not intentionally nullifying forbidden food).  Nonetheless, this does not appear to reflect normative practice.

However, in the case of "dairy" equipment, there appears to be the added issue that it is not clear that there was even bittul to begin with (i.e. based on the language cited above, it seems there is at least an additional uncertainty whether any given cookie has even a trace amount of dairy).

Accordingly, which halachic authorities (rishonim and/or achronim) does the OU rely on in crafting its ruling that even an alleged uncertainty (safek) of a possible trace amount of *heter* dairy should nonetheless prevent eating the overall product *together* with meat (assuming, of course, that Oreos are considered *nosein taam lishvach* [tasty] in a cholent)?

Comment: Click-bait title

Comment: How is this different from any other case of Nat bar Nat?

Comment: @DoubleAA Please CMIIAW but the description provided by the OU doesn't sound like they are describing *bliyos* of cooking equipment definitely used within 24 hrs. for dairy, but rather an uncertainty regarding whether a possible "residue" was left on the "equipment" (seemingly suggesting that which was used without heat).  Thus it seems like at least one safek of whether dairy was there at all to begin with, and even if it was, we are sure it is batel.  Do we say the Ramo's chumra of *nat bar nat* if we don't even have a certainty of chalav to begin with?

Comment: @ezra Nah. Just recipe suggestion;)

Comment: @Loewian While I disagree and think that they are assuming there are Ben Yomo Bliot at least in some of the batch, to address your question anyway it sounds just like they are presenting the Shakh 89 19 about a pot that you didn't clean fully (or some variation on his suggestion)

Comment: I think that @Joel K and I have the same impression: you're asking why we should distinguish (1) eating the cookies WITH meat from (2) eating the cookies IMMEDIATELY AFTER meat. Is that impression correct?

Answer (score 1):

The OU's psak is based on treating the cookies as a case of Nat bar Nat i.e. dairy 'taste' absorbed by the machinery is then considered to have been absorbed by the pareve cookies, **even if the machinery is completely clean of any dairy residue on the surface**.

The stringency not to eat such a food directly with meat, but to permit it immediately following meat, is based on [Rema Yoreh De'ah 95:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.95.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

[This article](http://etzion.org.il/en/nat-bar-nat-status-pareve-food-cooked-dairy-or-meat-pots) by R. David Brofsky gives a nice overview of the topic. Key quotes which are relevant here:

> The Rema notes that food which is fried or cooked in dairy utensils may not be eaten WITH meat.  However, this food may be eaten after meat, even during the same meal.  Therefore, one may serve a cake baked in a dairy pan for dessert after a meat meal.
>
> ...
>
> In recent years, terms such as "chezkat chalavi," or "dairy equipment," have entered the vocabulary of the kosher consumer.  These terms derive from this position of the Rema.  Food which was cooked in "dairy equipment" is considered "be-chezkat chalavi" and should not be eaten with meat, but may be consumed afterwards.  Furthermore, if it is unintentionally mixed with meat, the mixture may be eaten.

Comment: +1 for the sources but I'm not sure that answers the q. The description provided by the OU doesn't sound like they are describing *bliyos* of cooking equipment definitely used within 24 hrs. for dairy, but rather an uncertainty regarding whether a possible "residue" was left on the "equipment" (seemingly suggesting that which was used without heat).  Thus it seems like at least one safek of whether dairy was there at all to begin with, and even if it was, it is certainly batel.  The Ramo seems to be discussing where we are *sure* the pareve item was *cooked* in a *recently-used-for-dairy* pot.

Comment: @Loewian Can you provide a link to the OU’s explanation? Would be helpful to see the whole thing in context

Comment: https://oukosher.org/faqs/status-oreo-sandwich-cookies/

Comment: @Loewian Hmmm. Interesting. While I still stand by my answer, I see how the way they write it could be read in the way you do. Maybe call / email them to clarify...

Comment: Doesn't bliyas only occur with a liquid medium and enough heat from the food or equipment? Are these cookies really hot enough during production? What liquid is there? It seems unlikely that there's bliyas.

Comment: @Orion I don’t think there’s any reason to assume that bliyos only apply via liquid. In terms of heat, I would assume that the heat needed to bake the dough into cookies would be sufficient.

Comment: Joel K I also thought that it happens even without liquid (well tbh I doubt the very existence of a significant enough bliyas in metal especially in stainless steel but that's a moot point) but then I read this https://oukosher.org/publications/kli-el-kli-blo-rotaiv-lo-basi-ela-lorer/ Apparently it requires a liquid medium to transfer as long as they're both not fatty.