# Are Uncertified Lotus Biscoff Cookies Kosher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation

According to the [company website](http://www.biscoff.com/faq/174/are-lotus-biscoff-products-kosher):

> Lotus Biscoff Products are not Kosher certified.

From [Kosher.com](https://www.kosher.com/community/community-question/78):

> Note: Biscoff brand products, including Lotus Cookies, that are made in Belgium and are imported and sold in the US and Europe do not have a hechsher (kosher certification). Biscoff brand products that are produced for Israeli distribution are kosher and do have a hechsher in many kosher food stores around the world as an import from Israel. Please check products carefully for kosher certification before purchase.

The ingredients panel lists only:

> Wheat Flour, Sugar, Vegetable Oils (contains one or more of soy bean oil, sunflower oil, palm oil), Brown Sugar, Leavening (sodium bicarbonate), Soy Flour, Salt, Spice (cinnamon)

What would/could be the concern with uncertified packages?  What might the kosher-certifying agency be doing different in the "kosher runs" of the cookie?

Comment: What could be the concern, and What might they be doing, are very different questions from What is the concern, and What do they do. You ask the former in your post. I'm just checking that that's what you really mean to ask. (You may get answers like "the uncertified ones are _chadash_" or "the uncertified ones have sodium bicarbonate extracted from pork".)

Comment: Just please don't [put these in your cholent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91799/putting-oreos-in-your-cholent) :-)

Comment: @msh210 I'm hoping for an informed and inclusive answer (ideally that presents authoritative sources that the porcine bicarbonate is of course less of a concern than the spring wheat;)

Comment: It doesnt have any animal product they are certified vegetarian

Comment: @ShmuelBrin re the OU link - that seems to be more of a l'chumra - PR justification of certification - it doesn't explicitly address at all whether one is actually obligated to be concerned that uncertified vegetable oil isn't kosher (e.g. relying on kol d'parish etc.) In fact, DoubleAA's answer to the second link you provided indeed says that the OU rules accordingly for olive oil.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It could be indeed that the OU has determined that half of uncertified vegetable oils on the market do indeed taste better because of nonkosher contamination - but that seems highly improbable. Or, perhaps alternatively they rule that 1. at least a *miut hamatzui* [5-10%] of uncertified vegetable oils are actually not kosher, AND 2. an equivalently priced certified alternative is available, rendering the law equivalent to *efshar levarer* inasmuch as one could buy the certified product instead.  Otherwise, I have trouble seeing what the issue would be, at least based on dina dgmara

Comment: @avi more than that, on the same page on which they say that they are not kosher certified, they say that they are *vegan* - i.e. they should potentially even be pareve.

Comment: @Shmuel the question is if they specifically use a different oil for the kosher runs or there's the just a faint possibility they break from standard procedure and sneak lard into the uncertified ones, and then if halakha demands we be careful lest that happen

Comment: As of August 4, 2023, it appears the Delta Airlines Lotus Biscoff are now kosher, see https://www.dansdeals.com/more/news/airline-news/deltas-lotus-biscoff-cookies-now-certified-kosher-parve/

Answer (score -3):

first of all it is probably (99%) "bishul akum", 2ndly who checked or sift the flour?

Comment: Bishul Akum on a baked good?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Peter and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? And since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!