# The Secret of Nature Valley

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, hechsher-certification, taarovet

What, if any, might be legitimate halachik concerns with uncertified Nature Valley granola bars? Their ["Crunchy" line of products](https://www.naturevalley.com/products/?category=bars-all) seems to be certified as OU pareve(?) However, many of their other lines of products don't appear to be certified at all.

One example is their (dairy) [Sweet and Salty Nut Almond bars](https://www.naturevalley.com/product/sweet-and-salty-bars-almond/), which lists as its ingredients:

> Almonds, Corn Syrup, Whole Grain Oats, Sugar, Rice Flour, Palm Kernel Oil, Whole Grain Wheat, Vegetable Glycerin, Honey Roasted Almond Butter (almonds, honey, maltodextrin, palm oil, mixed tocopherols), Whey, Fructose, Canola Oil, Salt, Soy Lecithin, Corn Starch, Barley Malt Extract, Baking Soda, Natural Flavor, Vitamin E (mixed tocopherols) Added to Retain Freshness.

Likewise, their (nondairy) [Fruit & Nut Trailmix bars](https://www.naturevalley.com/product/fruit-and-nut-bars-trail-mix/) list:

> Whole Grain Oats, Corn Syrup, Almonds, Raisins, Sugar, Roasted Peanuts, Rice Flour, Vegetable Glycerin, Cranberries, Canola Oil, Fructose, Corn Starch, Soy Lecithin, Salt, Barley Malt Extract, Baking Soda, Natural Flavor, Mixed Tocopherols Added to Retain Freshness.

It seems highly implausible that the natural flavor might include, e.g., nonkosher animal products, especially considering that the same is listed in their OU-certified products.   Is there enough basis to assume that they are indeed kosher, at least *bediavad* (e.g. after purchase; or once in one's mouth)?

Related: [Are Uncertified Lotus Biscoff Cookies Kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91801/are-uncertified-lotus-biscoff-cookies-kosher)

Comment: http://www.ok.org/kosherspirit/fall-2015/glycerin/ "Glycerin is not “pogum” and usually it is not “botul b’shishim”. Glycerin or any product containing glycerin can only be used with acceptable kosher certification.

Comment: The assumption that 'natural flavors' are not potentially problematic is incorrect. A company may have different plants with different ingredients for the same flavor. So sometimes the flavor will be fine and will have a hechsher, and sometimes the same flavor will be made from bugs.

Comment: We do have something close to a generic "Why do we need a Hechsher" question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26655/does-every-thing-need-a-hechsher

Comment: Comments are not for discussion; please take it to [chat]. I've deleted a bunch.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://learn.oheltorah.com/t/non-hechsher-kashrut/8497/8), the problem is that the machine line they use to make these bars is not kosher.